# Convert the elastic search response to a list

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, json-deserialization

I am using elastic 7.17.3 and NEST 7.17.3
I have a elastic response which I am trying to put in a list. I have below method. The method is generic and is called from different model classes.

```
public class Account
    {
        [JsonProperty(AnalyticsFields.AccessRegions)]
        public string[] AccessRegions { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(AnalyticsFields.AccessUsers)]
        public string[] AccessUsers { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(AnalyticsFields.AccountId)]
        public string AccountId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(AnalyticsFields.AccountIdAndName)]
        public string AccountIdAndName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(AnalyticsFields.AdvisorId)]
        public string AdvisorId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(AnalyticsFields.AdvisorIdAndName)]
        public string AdvisorIdAndName { get; set; }
        
    }
```

This is how the method converting the elastic response looks like

```
private void AddSearchResponseHits<T>(ISearchResponse<T> searchResponse, List<T> results) where T : class
        {
            results.AddRange(searchResponse.Hits.Select(h => h.Source).ToArray());
        }
```

The problem is the field value becomes null even thought the searchresponse have the complete response from elastic. Please help me out. The field values should load in respective properties in the model class.

Comment: Did you try with `searchResponse.Documents` already?